# Question on using Zondervan resources by Catholics

Tags: catholicism, books

I'm thinking of purchasing 2 books specifically grounded in biblical archaeology published by Zondervan. The first is called *Handbook of Biblical Archaeology* and the second is the *NIV Archaeological Study Bible* in which the footnotes are mostly grounded in archaeology than in theology.

As a Catholic, would these resources be okay to read from?

Answer (score 2):

If you ask if the [*Index Librorum Prohibitorum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_Librorum_Prohibitorum) still exists and has the force of (Canon) Law, the answer is no. The reforms of Pope Paul VI in 1966 and the statements from the Congregation for Doctrine of the Faith in that same year in effect ended the Index as a legally binding instrument.

But that does *not* mean the Church no longer warns you not to read books that are possibly dangerous for faith or morals.

The easiest way to go forward would be to ask your Bishop to give advice on this. If that is, for whatever reason, not a possibility, ask a priest (or yes, even a deacon) for advice.

And if THAT doesn’t work for you, listen to your conscience.

Answer (score 2):

**Question on Zondervan source materials?**

Both the *Handbook of Biblical Archaeology* and also the *NIV Archaeological study bible* should be fine to read. Neither one has been flagged by the Church.

Being a non-Catholic source of information, any questions or doubts should be brought up to a priest or deacon!

Answer (score 1):

I have a copy of the *NIV Archaeological Study Bible* and although I am not a Catholic, I can vouch for the usefulness of its many interesting sidebars and articles. The NIV itself is not among my favorite translations. As I'm sure the OP knows it is not listed among the [approved translations](https://www.usccb.org/offices/new-american-bible/approved-translations-bible) for Catholics, but the value of the book is not in the NIV translation.

I used to hold Bible studies in my living room. We used several different translations, and it was always interesting to see how various translators handled the material. We often benefited from Archaeological Study Bible. It was a very useful tool for adding important background material to our readings. I still consult it today from time to time. You should talk to your priest about it to be sure but as long as you don't rely on the NIV itself as your primary translation, you should be on solid ground.

Answer (score 1):

The Handbook of Biblical Archaeology probably won't have much in the way of a theological bent, so you probably don't have to worry about it. It comes from their academic imprint as well, which means that it's more likely to be intended for an ecumenical audience than the more evangelically slanted core market for Zondervan.

Zondervan is typically going to be rather ecumenical in their study Bibles, barring a couple options that have a more particular denominational affiliation. The Archaeology Study Bible should be relatively light on theology, so you probably won't encounter too much stuff. Obviously it will be missing the Deuterocanon in the NIV Archaeology Study Bible.

I'm not Catholic myself, but I've had a lot of experience in and around the Catholic Church (including several close Catholic acquaintances and working in the local Diocese). If you have serious concerns, I'd ask someone like a priest, bishop, or deacon, but probably you don't have to worry inasmuch as the content is going to be primarily non-theological (or it will focus on the general shared beliefs of all Christians more broadly, such as potentially having some findings that dispute modern atheist or neo-gnostic attacks on the faith).

Zondervan, Thomas Nelson, and Catholic Bible Press are owned by Harper-Collins and tend to peek at each others' notes. This means there's sometimes a stronger ecumenical bent than people appreciate at first, especially in things like study Bibles that don't have a strict denominational affiliation (consider Nelson's Timeless Truth and Ancient-Modern study Bibles, which have a pretty strong mix of Orthodox and Catholic thought for a publisher associated primarily with evangelicals).